# How to determine right size thermistor

Tags: thermistor

I have a blown 15A fuse and a red thermistor about 16 mm in diameter that has blown I can’t get any info on it as I don’t have a part number any suggestions what size the thermistor might be so I can replace it

---

[image]

This is closeup of what I assume was thermistor

Comment: Can you be sure it's a thermistor and, if you can, can you post the schematic that has it.

Comment: Good chance it's not a thermistor but rather a MOV. Post a clear well-cropped photo including a bit of the surrounding circuitry.